# Indexed TableView (A to Z) not working correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, indexing

I have a simple app showing functionaries, functions, employees, etc…

I inserted a SearchBar and it is working great! But I am having some difficult to put a indexed TableView (I decided to use `UILocalizedIndexedCollation`). Take a look at my main TableViewController:

```
import UIKit

class Page1: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    var employeesSearching = [Employee]()
    var isSearching : Bool = false

    let collation = UILocalizedIndexedCollation.current()
    var sections: [[AnyObject]] = []
    var objects: [AnyObject] = [] {
        didSet {
            let selector: Selector = #selector(getter: UIApplicationShortcutItem.localizedTitle)
            sections = Array(repeating: [], count: collation.sectionTitles.count)

            let sortedObjects = collation.sortedArray(from: objects, collationStringSelector: selector)
            for object in sortedObjects {
                let sectionNumber = collation.section(for: object, collationStringSelector: selector)
                sections[sectionNumber].append(object as AnyObject)
            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.searchBar.delegate = self
        self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: searchBar.frame.height)
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int { return sections.count }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return isSearching ? employeesSearching.count : sections[section].count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell1
        let entry = isSearching ? employeesSearching[indexPath.row] : Shared.instance.employees[indexPath.row]

        //Do I have to put (sections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]) here? ok, but how?

        cell.nameLabel.text = entry.name
        cell.positionLabel.text = entry.position

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return collation.sectionTitles[section]
    }

    override func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
        return collation.sectionIndexTitles
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, at index: Int) -> Int {
        return collation.section(forSectionIndexTitle: index)
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if self.searchBar.text!.isEmpty {
            self.isSearching = false
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            self.isSearching = true
            self.employeesSearching.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
            let searchText = self.searchBar.text!.lowercased()
            for employee in Shared.instance.employees {

                if employee.name.lowercased().range(of: searchText) != nil {
                    self.employeesSearching.append(employee)
                }
            }
        }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "ShowP2" {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let employee: Employee
                isSearching == true && searchBar.text != "" ?
                    (employee = employeesSearching[indexPath.row]) : (employee = Shared.instance.employees[indexPath.row])
                let destination = segue.destination as? Page2
                destination?.newPage = employee
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT 1: My data**

I am importing my data from a plist by the AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "directory", withExtension: "plist"), let array = NSArray(contentsOf: url) as? [[String:Any]] {
            Shared.instance.employees = array.map{Employee(dictionary: $0)}
        }
        return true
}
```

It was all ok (and not empty) before I used `UILocalizedIndexedCollation`, but now it is all empty:

[image: app]

Comment: what is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: TableView is empty because I don't know how to use sections on func `cellForRowAt `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have implement TableView cellforRowAt, Problem could be

1) Your labels are not constraint well. You can check it by adding a background color of the labels.

2) You don't have any data.

Comment: Just updated my question. My constraints are ok and also my data. I know the problem is on `cellForRowAt`. I just don't know how to fix it.